# How can I traverse xml nodes without knowing its schema

Tags: java, xml

I know I can use DocumentBuilder to parse an xml file and traverse through the nodes but I am stuck at figuring out if the node has any more children. So for example in this xml:

```
<MyDoc>
 <book>
   <title> ABCD </title>
 </book>
</MyDoc>
```

if I do node.hasChildNodes() I get true for both book and title. But what I am trying to do is if a node has some text value (not attributes) like title then print it otherwise don't do anything. I know this is some simple check but I just can't seem to find the answer on web. I am probably not searching with right keywords. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try getChildNodes(). That will return a NodeList object which will allow you to iterate through all of the Nodes under the one you're referencing. regardless of what names they might have.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the type of the child nodes that you get by calling `getChildNodes()`by calling `getNodeType()`. `<book>` has a child of type `ELEMENT_NODE` whereas `<title>` has a child of type `TEXT_NODE`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you wanted a way to iterate through all of the elements regardless of how nested it is. The below recursively goes through all elements. It then prints the elements value as long as its not just white space:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException 
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = builder.parse("test.xml");
    NodeList childNodes = doc.getChildNodes();
    iterateNodes(childNodes);
}

private static void iterateNodes(NodeList childNodes) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); ++i)
    {
        Node node = childNodes.item(i);
        String text = node.getNodeValue();
        if (text != null && !text.trim().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(text);
        }
        if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
            iterateNodes(node.getChildNodes());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Text nodes exist under element nodes in a DOM, and data is always stored in text nodes. Perhaps the most common error in DOM processing is to navigate to an element node and expect it to contain the data that is stored in that element. Not so! Even the simplest element node has a text node under it that contains the data.

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html